# If $\sigma(N) = aN + b$, where $\gcd(a, b) = 1$, does it follow that at least one of $N$'s factors is solitary?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisor-sum

Let $\sigma(x)$ be the sum of the divisors of $x$.

If $\sigma(N) = aN + b$, where $\gcd(a, b) = 1$, $a \geq 2$, and $b$ could be negative, does it follow that at least one of $N$'s factors is [solitary](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SolitaryNumber.html)?

Of course, we exclude the case $p \mid N$ or $q^k \mid N$, where $p$ and $q$ are primes, and $k \geq 1$, as it is already known that primes and powers of primes are solitary.

Comment: This comment does not directly address the original question, but there are some related considerations in the paper [Variations on Euclid’s Formula for Perfect Numbers](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL13/Hasler/hasler2.pdf) by Farideh Firoozbakht and Maximilian F. Hasler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(This is only a partial answer to the question.)

If $\sigma(N) = {a_1}N + 1$ for some $a_1 \geq 2$, then $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a_1,1)=1$.  Additionally, $\gcd(N,\sigma(N))=\gcd(N,{a_1}N+1)=1$, since $\sigma(N)-{a_1}N=1$ expresses $1$ as a linear combination of $\sigma(N)$ and $N$.  Therefore, $N$ itself is solitary.

A similar result holds for $M$ when
$$\sigma(M) = {a_2}M - 1.$$

The situation when $b = 0$ leads to the study of *(multi)perfects*, and (therefore?) remains open.  Similarly, the case $|b| > 1$ appears (?) to be intractable.

(I'm flagging this as **community wiki** in case somebody else is able to settle the remaining cases.)