# Is $p(p + 1)$ always a friendly number for $p$ a prime number?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, conjectures, divisor-sum

Let $\sigma(x)$ denote the sum of the divisors of $x$.  We call the ratio $I(x) = \sigma(x)/x$ as the **abundancy index** of $x$.

A positive integer $N$ is [friendly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friendly_number) if there exists a positive integer $M \neq N$ such that $I(M) = I(N)$.

My question is the following:

> Is $Z = p(p + 1) = p\sigma(p)$ always a friendly number for $p$ a prime number?

Note that
$$\gcd(Z, \sigma(Z)) = \gcd(p(p + 1), (p + 1)\sigma(p + 1)) \geq p + 1 \geq 3,$$
so that Greening's Theorem fails to establish solitude.

OEIS sequence [A074902](http://oeis.org/A074902) lists the following as friendly:
$$6, 12, 30, 56, 132$$
but does not list $182$ and $306$, for example.

Comment: If either of $182$ or $306$ is friendly, the other friendly is known to be $>10^{30}$, whereas the other friendly is [significantly smaller when known](http://oeis.org/A050973). This makes it somewhat unlikely that $182$ is friendly. Do you have any reason to support the idea that such numbers are friendly?

Comment: I honestly don't know how to answer your question, @HagenvonEitzen.  But I think this question occurred to me while I was trying construct a counterexample to my question in this earlier [MSE post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1522499).