# If $\gcd(Z,\sigma(Z))=1$ and $1<N=Z\sigma(Z)$, is $N$ always friendly?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, conjectures, divisor-sum

This question is a generalization / offshoot of this earlier [MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1522550):

> If $\gcd(Z,\sigma(Z))=1$ and $1<N=Z\sigma(Z)$, is $N$ always [friendly](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FriendlyNumber.html)?

Here, $\gcd(a,b)$ is the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$, and $\sigma(x)$ is the sum of the divisors of $x$.

Note that
$$\gcd(N,\sigma(N))=\gcd(Z\sigma(Z),\sigma(Z\sigma(Z)))=\gcd(Z\sigma(Z),\sigma(Z)\sigma(\sigma(Z))) \geq \sigma(Z) > 1$$
where the last inequality follows from $1<N=Z\sigma(Z)$, so that Greening's Theorem fails to establish that $N$ is solitary.  (However, this does **not** *conclusively* prove that $N$ is friendly.)

For an example:  Consider $Z = 2^{p-1}$ where $p$ and $2^p - 1$ are primes.

There does not seem to be a sequence in [OEIS](http://oeis.org) for

> Numbers $n$ such that $\gcd(n,\sigma(n))=1$ and $n\sigma(n)$ is friendly.

Comment: The first _possible_ counterexample could be $Z=9$ which gives $N=Z\sigma(Z)=9\cdot 13=117$. So does $117$ have a friend? After cancelling the $13$ from numerator and denominator, $\frac{\sigma(117)}{117}=\frac{14}{9}$. As far as I know, $117$ could be solitary. So I conjecture the answer to your question is no.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen, can you write out your last comment into an actual answer and include a reference to the conjecture that $117$ is solitary as needs be, so that I may be able to accept it?  Thanks!