# Why is proving that $10$ is solitary considered very difficult?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, conjectures, divisor-sum

The title says it all.

We denote the sum of the divisors of $x$ by $\sigma(x)$.  The ratio $I(x)=\sigma(x)/x$ is called the *abundancy index* of $x$.  If $I(m)=I(n)$, then $\{m,n\}$ is called a *friendly pair*.  A number which is not a member of a friendly pair is called *solitary*.

So:

> Why is proving that $10$ is solitary considered **very difficult**?

Is there no (known) *partial* converse to Greening's Theorem (i.e., $\gcd(N, \sigma(N)) = 1 \implies N$ is solitary)?  What is the main obstruction?

OEIS sequence [A014567](http://oeis.org/A014567) contains the following statement from [Dean Hickerson](http://genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/id.php?id=31450):

> It is easy to show that if $N$ and $\sigma(N)$ are relatively prime then $N$ is solitary. But the converse is not true; for example, $18$, $45$, $48$ and $52$ are solitary. Probably also $10$, $14$, $15$, $20$, $22$ and many others are solitary, but I do not think that will ever be proved.

**Update (November 11, 2015)**: I am aware of the paper [Does Ten Have a Friend?](http://arxiv.org/abs/0806.1001), which gives some necessary conditions for a number to be a friend of $10$.  This question is essentially an offshoot of the following earlier MSE posts:

1. [Can distinct odd perfect numbers $N = {p^k}{m^2}$ share the same Euler factor $p^k$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1522326)
2. [If $\sigma(N) = aN + b$, where $\gcd(a, b) = 1$, does it follow that at least one of $N$'s factors is solitary?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1522499)
3. [Is $p(p + 1)$ always a friendly number for $p$ a prime number?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1522550)

Comment: I don't think Hickerson's statement says that specifically "proving that 10 is solitary" is very difficult, but the "many others" part, i.e. finding a large (new) collection of numbers that are all solitary.

Comment: @vadim123, I quote the [Wolfram MathWorld article on solitary numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SolitaryNumber.html): "It is believed that $$10, 14, 15, 20, 22, 26, 33, 34, 38, 44, 46, 51, 54, 58, 62, 68, 69, 70, 72, 74, 76, 82, 86, 87, 88, 90, 91, 92, 94, 95, 99, 104, 105, 106,$$ and many others are also solitary, although a proof appears to be extremely difficult."  I therefore agree with the essence of your comment.

Comment: This is the kind of questions about which erdoes said : Mathematics is not ready yet to answer this question. (If I remember right, he particular made this statement as a comment about Collatz's conjecture).